# ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider: Getting UserDetails

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, active-directory

I followed the following tutorial in order to get Spring and Rest working with full security and stateless tokens.

http://captechconsulting.com/blog/jens-alm/versioned-validated-and-secured-rest-services-spring-40-4

I am now trying to convert the authentications mechanism to use Active Directory (ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider). My issue is that I can not figure out how to get to the UserDetails so the  loadUserByUsername(userName) method can be utilized.

Below is method that is causing me problems, the commented line provides the user detail service to the filter but I can not figure out how to get this information using Active Directory authentication.

```
 private Filter authenticationFilter() {
        HeaderAuthenticationFilter headerAuthenticationFilter = new HeaderAuthenticationFilter();

        //headerAuthenticationFilter.userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        headerAuthenticationFilter.headerUtil(headerUtil);
        return headerAuthenticationFilter;
    }
```

Below is my Spring Security Configuration and utilized class.

SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String ACCESS_DENIED_JSON = "{\"message\":\"You are not privileged to request this resource.\", \"access-denied\":true,\"cause\":\"AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE\"}";
    private static final String UNAUTHORIZED_JSON = "{\"message\":\"Full authentication is required to access this resource.\", \"access-denied\":true,\"cause\":\"NOT AUTHENTICATED\"}";

    @Autowired
    private HeaderUtil headerUtil;

//    @Autowired
//    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
//        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().
//
//                withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").
//
//                and().
//
//                withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
//    }
//    
    @Bean
    public ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("domain.com", "ldap://ad.domain.com:389");
        provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);

        //provider.setAuthoritiesMapper( new NullAuthoritiesMapper()); // see http://comdynamics.net/blog/544/spring-security-3-integration-with-active-directory-ldap/


        return provider;
    }


    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler = new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        successHandler.headerUtil(headerUtil);

        http.
                addFilterBefore(corsFilter(), LogoutFilter.class).
                addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), LogoutFilter.class).

                csrf().disable().

                formLogin().successHandler(successHandler).
                loginProcessingUrl("/login").

                and().

                logout().
                logoutSuccessUrl("/logout").

                and().

                sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).

                and().

                exceptionHandling().
                accessDeniedHandler(new CustomAccessDeniedHandler()).
                authenticationEntryPoint(new CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint()).

                and().

                authorizeRequests().
                antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll().
                antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/logout").authenticated().
//                antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").hasRole("USER").
//                antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**").hasRole("ADMIN").
//                antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/**").hasRole("ADMIN").
                antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").authenticated().
                antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**").authenticated().
                antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/**").authenticated().
                anyRequest().authenticated();

    }

    private Filter authenticationFilter() {
        HeaderAuthenticationFilter headerAuthenticationFilter = new HeaderAuthenticationFilter();

        //headerAuthenticationFilter.userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        headerAuthenticationFilter.headerUtil(headerUtil);
        return headerAuthenticationFilter;
    }


    private Filter corsFilter() {
        return new SimpleCORSFilter();
    }

    private static class CustomAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {
        @Override
        public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException, ServletException {

            response.setContentType(Versions.V1_0);
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.print(ACCESS_DENIED_JSON);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

        }
    }

    private static class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
        @Override
        public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {

            response.setContentType(Versions.V1_0);
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.print(UNAUTHORIZED_JSON);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
    }

    private static class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

        private HeaderUtil headerUtil;

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                            Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {
            try {
                String token = headerUtil.createAuthToken(((LdapUserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal()).getUsername());
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                ObjectNode node = mapper.createObjectNode().put("x-auth-token", token);
                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                out.print(node.toString());
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
                throw new ServletException("Unable to create the auth token", e);
            }
            clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);

        }

        private void headerUtil(HeaderUtil headerUtil) {
            this.headerUtil = headerUtil;
        }
    }

}
```

HeaderAuthenticationFilter

```
public class HeaderAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {


    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    private HeaderUtil headerUtil;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        UserDetails userDetails = loadUserDetails((HttpServletRequest) request);
        SecurityContext contextBeforeChainExecution = createSecurityContext(userDetails);

        try {
            SecurityContextHolder.setContext(contextBeforeChainExecution);
            if (contextBeforeChainExecution.getAuthentication() != null && contextBeforeChainExecution.getAuthentication().isAuthenticated()) {
                String userName = (String) contextBeforeChainExecution.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
                headerUtil.addHeader((HttpServletResponse) response, userName);
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
        finally {
            // Clear the context and free the thread local
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        }
    }

    private SecurityContext createSecurityContext(UserDetails userDetails) {
        if (userDetails != null) {
            SecurityContextImpl securityContext = new SecurityContextImpl();
            Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails.getUsername(), userDetails.getPassword(), userDetails.getAuthorities());
            securityContext.setAuthentication(authentication);
            return securityContext;
        }
        return SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
    }

    private UserDetails loadUserDetails(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String userName = headerUtil.getUserName(request);

        return userName != null
                ? userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userName)
                : null;
    }

    public void userDetailsService(UserDetailsService userDetailsService2) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService2;
    }

    public void headerUtil(HeaderUtil headerUtil) {
        this.headerUtil = headerUtil;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring LDAP has something called [LdapUserDetailsService](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.0.M2/reference/htmlsingle/#ldap-custom-user-details) and I'm going to go out on a limb and say that this could be the one you will have to be doing. Typically, Spring comes with sensible defaults and we just to wire the correct things.

Comment: So the UserDetailsService wasn't oringally autowired. That is something I added trying to resolve my issue. I have also tried using the LdapUserDetailsService but I am unsure how to properly get an instance of it. The current UserDetailsService object is defined when the security config is created and uses a method proved by the @EnableWebMvcSecurity tag.